# Apache ignite RDD with custom classes

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, ignite

I am new to Ignite, while following the example in [Ignite Spark Tutorial](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.2/docs/ignitecontext--igniterdd), I was trying to see if similar steps may be used with a custom type (a case class) as in `IgniteRDD[Int, CastomClass]` as opposed to `IgniteRDD[Integer, Integer]`.  I able to create the RDD and call `savePairs` on it, however I am unable to then read the data back out.  Here is some sample code, I will not bore you with details of text processing RDD transform steps

#### Storing

```
import org.apache.ignite.spark._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, "examples/config/spark/example-shared-rdd.xml", true)

case class CustomType(tid: String, subtid: String, value: Double)

val cacheRdd = ic.fromCache[Int, CustomType]("TEST")
// numbered custom entries is a Spark RDD[Int, CustomType]
cacheRdd.savePairs(numberedCustomEntries)
```

#### Retreiving

```
cachedRdd.first
```

This results in a long stack trace the gist of it being that my custom class is not found

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CustomType`.  Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: Where does the error occur? Driver, executor, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend using a new documentation instead of the old one: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd

I see here 2 possible problems:

- in config file, for the cache configuration, you replaced java.lang.Integer with CustomType instead of the full name with package.
- you don't have class CustomType in classpaths of some nodes.

Comment: Evegenii, perhaps I made some naive assumptions, but I thought that just declaring the case class in my spark REPL would take care of having to distribute the class (at least in the prototyping phase)

Comment: One more thing, I have created a separate class to represent my data model, wrapped it in a JAR and passed it to spark.  I am still seeing the same error when I ask the shared RDD for data by using any actions such as `first` or `take`

Comment: If you are still having ClassNotFoundException, then it is certainly a class path issue. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my custom JAR need to live in `$IGNITE_HOME/libs`

> scala> sharedRDD.first
>   [10:35:57] Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=2, clients=1, CPUs=8, heap=2.8GB]
>   res1: (Int, CustomData) = (242691,CustomData [Id=XYZ, sId=XYZ001, value=6.0E8])